# State not mounting with componentWillMount

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have a treenode and I'm trying to display content after user selects a node but the content is not changing.

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      t:["",""],
      loading: false,
      disPageTken:"",
    };
  }
```

```
  componentWillMount(){

     window.FB.api(
    '/me',
    'GET',
    {"fields":"posts{created_time,likes,comments,picture,full_picture,shares,message},name,picture","access_token":this.state.disPageTken},

    function(response) {
      console.log(response)
      if (response.posts) {
        let listData = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < response.posts.data.length; i++) {
            listData.push({//code})
            }

          this.setState({ listposts: listData });
        } else {
          console.log(response.error);
        }
      }.bind(this)
          );
}
```

```
<DirectoryTree showIcon
                defaultSelectedKeys={['0']}
                switcherIcon={<Icon type="down" />} multiple defaultExpandAll onSelect={this.onSelect} onExpand={this.onExpand}>

                <TreeNode icon={<Icon type="facebook" />} title="Facebook" key="0-0" >
                  <TreeNode key="0" icon={({ selected }) => <Icon type={selected ? 'facebook' : 'frown-o'} />} title="Test Page1" key="0" isLeaf/>
                  <TreeNode
                    icon={({ selected }) => <Icon type={selected ? 'facebook' : 'frown-o'} />}
                    title="Test Page2"
                    key="1"
                    isLeaf
                  />
                </TreeNode>
              </DirectoryTree>
```

I don't understand why, I tried with componentDidMount but I think something's not detecting changes?

Answer (score 2):

A few things here.

Your state is not changing because the function in which you call `setState` has a different value for `this` than you're expecting. If you check the console, you should see an error indicating that `this.setState` is not a function. You need to change the following:

```
window.FB.api('/me', 'GET', {"fields":"posts{created_time,likes,comments,picture,full_picture,shares,message},name,picture","access_token":this.state.disPageTken},
function(response) {
  console.log(response)
```

To this:

```
window.FB.api('/me', 'GET', {"fields":"posts{created_time,likes,comments,picture,full_picture,shares,message},name,picture","access_token":this.state.disPageTken},
(response) => {
  console.log(response)
```

The arrow function captures the current value of `this`, so this code will work as expected.

Secondly, *do not* use `componentWillMount()` for side effects (such as fetching) - ideally, don't use it at all. It may be called multiple times when a component is mounted, which will lead to multiple fetches. It does not exist in newer versions of React (it is renamed `UNSAFE_componentWillMount())` and [will be removed in a future version of React](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount).

Instead, use `componentDidMount()`. It is only called once, when the component is mounted.